# Force a printer into an error state

Tags: java, printing

I'm trying to reproduce a behaviour of a java applet when it sends a print job and a `javax.print.PrintException: Printer is not accepting job` exception is thrown.

I'm trying to follow the steps in the first comment of [this issue of open JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046007).

My question is:
How do I place a printer in an error state. It would be awesome if I could do it with PDFCreator for instance or some other virtual printer I could easily test.

Quoting the steps:

> 4. Make the printer go to an error condition. The easiest way to do it is to disconnect network cable from your laptop/desktop if you have a network printer or to power off your printer if it's local.

I disconnected the network cable from my laptop and then sent the job to my network printer only to receive a different exception:

`java.awt.print.PrinterException: The RPC server is unavailable.`

I've tried fiddling with restarts of the spooler service while I paused the printer or restricted the print times, trying to get a print job in an error state. I also tried opening the shd files trying to edit them to force the error state on the jobs but I could not find out how, nor it would do anything as the starting of the spooler service would clear the folder...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

Go to the printer properties and in the ports tab just change it to something like COM1.

Apply and try to print. The document will be in an error state which was what I needed since the printer is considered to be in an error state after that.